# How to interact with R from VBA?

Tags: r, vba

Suppose I have VBA macro in Excel which does some calculation. And I would like to do a part of this calculation in R, but in program mode. Say, at some moment Excel macro has a vector and it needs to find its mean by mean function in R. How can I call R from VBA, transmit a vector to R, initiate the calculation in R and get back the result in VBA? Thanks.

Comment: You might have to go via c or c++, unless R exposes a COM interface.

Answer (score 4):

There is a plugin RExcel, but I found quite horrible to use it (and you kinda have to pay for it).

The easiest and most general but hacky way to perform your interaction is the following:

1) Save your array/matrix/vector in csv in a folder

2) write your R code in a file that read the csv and write the result in csv

3) Call the R script from VBA with the VBA Shell function (Rscript scriptName.R)

4) Import the result back to excel/VBA.

This method has the advantage that you are separating the computational logic with the formatting from VBA.

You could also call the R code directly within VBA with -e option from R but this is strongly unadvised.

Hope it helps!

BTW: it works with all the other program (Python/LaTeX/Matlab).